# Nested for loop updating 3 variables at the same time

Tags: javascript, loops

I have looked around, but found no solution.

I want to print out the 'interpolation' points between this:

```
.card.ani25 {
bottom: 72%;
left:85%;
}
```

and this:

```
.card.ani49 {
bottom: 46%;
left: 46%;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to update all numerical values in that CSS at the same time. Updating one value at a time works, but is of no use in this case.
What I have tried so far, well, everything coming to mind, including triggering some infinite loops, but this is what is "stable":-)

```
for (var i = 25; i < 50; i++){
 for (var j = 72; j >=46; j-=2){
  for (var k = 85; k >=46; k-=3){
t.innerHTML = '.card.ani' + i + ' {' + '<br>' + 'bottom: ' + j + '%;' + '<br>' + 'left: ' + k + '%;' + '<br>' + '}';
  }
 }
}
```

This only prints out the final iteration, as can be seen here:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ZLEXOR

If I put a += after the "innerHTML2, it blows up, screen freezes, just like an infinite loop.

I know, the outermost loop runs first, then the next inner loop second multiple times, but I have never seen a case with 3 variables. Honestly, I wouldn't know the solution for 2 variables only either.

Thanks and very sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: `=` is assignment so you are overwriting the HTML each time, that's why you only see the last iteration. Using `+=` will not make it an infinite loop, it will loop just as much each time. But considering there are 2 nested loops it will be a large string, with it being that large it will take some time to process.

Comment: Try building string value in a separate variable and outside the loops make an assignment `t.innerHTML = str;`

Comment: Just want to make it clear, `+=` slow because you are re-writing the HTML with each iteration. Those constant re-writes to that `.innerHTML` value is what is slowing it down, but it still works. Doing what *@Igor Nikolaev* mentioned and it will be faster because you are only assigning `.innerHTML` once at the end. [For example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEjrBj).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, thanks, however, it actually freezes the tab up.or almost. I have tried now with textContent +=, this does not freeze up, the loop runs, but the result is not what I want it to be. I want the class value to be increased by 1 and at the same time the 2 percentage values as well. However, the loop first runs the innermost loop first, without updating the i and j variables:-(

Comment: @ptts what is your goal? It looks like you are doing some kind of animation. It might be possible that you can use CSS transformations and transitions to do the same. Maybe you can shed some more light on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ptts That's how loops work. The very inner loops iterates first for each iteration of it's parent. If you want to change `i`,`j`, and `k` each time then you only need a single loop. You need to be more clear what you mean by *'interpolation' points*.

Comment: Igor, i'm buildng a game, i only need this loop to not write out the socalled interpolation points, see this pen  http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/EZYzpY
see the css from line 130, so yeah its just for that.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, oops, so  single loop would be sufficient? Would you be so kind and help me with that:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is is that the operation for changing HTML through reassigning `innerHTML` is slow. When you use `+=` it will rewrite the HTML each time, that's what's causing it to slow down. That said it still works, a faster way to do this is use a variable to hold the string and update that variable. Then at the end assign the value of `t.innerHTML` to that string:

```
var t = document.getElementById('target');
var str = "";
for (var i = 25; i < 50; i++){
 for (var j = 72; j >=46; j-=2){
  for (var k = 85; k >=46; k-=3){
      str += '.card.ani' + i + ' {' + '<br>' + 'bottom: ' + j + '%;' + '<br>' + 'left: ' + k + '%;' + '<br>' + '}';
    }
  }
}

t.innerHTML = str;
```

---

**Edit**

After clarification it appears you only want a single loop and update the variables each time in that loop. In that case you can do something like:

```
var t = document.getElementById('target');
var str = "";
for (var i = 25, j = 72, k = 85; i < 50 && j >=46 && k >=46; i++, j-=2, k-=3){
    str += '.card.ani' + i + ' {' + '<br>' + 'bottom: ' + j + '%;' + '<br>' + 'left: ' + k + '%;' + '<br>' + '}';
}
t.innerHTML = str;
```

For each section inside a for loop `for(x;y;z)` you can use a comma to make many statements. So in the first section you can define 3 variables and in the last section update 3 variables. The middle section runs the loop as long as all of those conditions are met, when a single one fails it stops.

*Note*: You can use `||` (*OR*) if you would like it to keep going as long as one of the conditions are true.

**[Code Pen (single loop)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgYePg)**

[**Code Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEjrBj)

Comment: Ah, that is much faster, however, it only updates the k value at first. It runs the innermost loop first and does not update the i and j values. The goal would be to update all 3 variable with each iteraion:-) I have seen it before in Java, but can't find that code or reproduce it.

Comment: @ptts Are you looking for something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgYePg). Seems like are you want is a single loop that and change each variable on that loop.

Comment: Perfect! Use that as perfect answer:-)

Comment: Learned a lot today:-) Bit embarassing to have never heard of this concept o0 This will save me so much time on some verbose projects:-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd promote a very different approach.

I think of this as a number of distinct ranges that need to be animated over in parallel.  So I would like to have a function that knows how to do just that.

```
const rangeFns = (...configs) => fn => val => 
  fn.apply(null, configs.map(cfg => (cfg.end - cfg.start) * val + cfg.start))
```

This takes a collection of range descriptions and returns a function that accepts a custom function with one parameter for each of those ranges and finally returns a simple function that accepts a number between 0 and 1, returning the result of your custom function with the interpolation for each range being supplied for the respective parameter.  That's a bit of a mouthful, but I think it's easy to use:

```
const anim = rangeFns(
  {start: 25, end: 49},
  {start: 72, end: 46},
  {start: 85, end: 46}
)((ani, bottom, left) => `
  .card.ani${Math.round(ani)} {
    bottom: ${bottom}%;
    left: ${left};
  }`
);
```

If you ran this with values 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,  and 1, you'd get these results:

```
.card.ani25 {
  bottom: 72%;
  left: 85;
}

.card.ani31 {
  bottom: 65.5%;
  left: 75.25;
}

.card.ani37 {
  bottom: 59%;
  left: 65.5;
}

.card.ani43 {
  bottom: 52.5%;
  left: 55.75;
}

.card.ani49 {
  bottom: 46%;
  left: 46;
}
```

(Obviously you could add rounding to `bottom` and `left` if that's desired.)

You could then use this in an animation, by passing values calculated from your start and finish times.

To my mind the advantage is that this is more explicit.  It makes the ranges more declarative, and makes the function that uses the results a lot more straightforward.

A version of this is available on **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/CrossEye/pen/jyOaOQ)**.

### Update

A slightly better version of this would be to use arrays rather than objects.  (I originally had additional parameters in there that turned out unnecessary.  I didn't notice that removing them allowed for a nice clean-up.)

```
const multiRange = (...ranges) => fn => val => 
  fn.apply(null, ranges.map(range => (range[1] - range[0]) * val + range[0]))

const anim = multiRange([25, 49], [72, 46], [85, 46])((ani, bottom, left) => `
  .card.ani${Math.round(ani)} {
    bottom: ${bottom}%;
    left: ${left};
  }`
);
```

I think this reads better.

This version is also on **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/CrossEye/pen/OWJQjp?editors=1010)**.

Comment: This is very nice, this is perfect for the projectsI have in mind.Thnaks for this, forked:-) Btw, the purpose is exactly to draw animation paths, and it helps a great deal to keep writing repetitive code down:-)

Comment: @ptts: Thanks.  Updated with a slightly nicer version.